# Why does find not match repeat / quantifier expressions with emacs regular expressions?

Tags: find, regular-expression

I have a file 'abcd' in my current dir.
Using `find -regex '\.\/[a-d]\{4\}'` gets me no results. While the regex works fine in emacs itself.

`find`, however, does find my file when I add `-regextype posix-basic` option to it.

Yet, the find manual specifies that find uses emacs regex by default. So why don't the quantifiers work?